# issues web scraping data and creating a data frame in Pandas (likely an easy answer)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I am web scraping pubmed.gov abstracts and while I can get the data I need and print it, I can't export it into a Python Pandas export.  For some reason, I am only getting the first result when I export it to an Excel file. I appreciate any help! So my question is why am I only getting the first URL and abstract and how would I adjust my code to get all? My code is shown below:

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 from urllib.request import urlopen
 import requests
 import pandas as pd

 abstracturllist = ['https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31098966', 
'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31067303', 
'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31045693']

 for th in abstracturllist:

      response = requests.get(th)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
      x = soup.select('div.abstr')[0].prettify()
      data = {'URL':[th],'abstract':[x]}
      df = pd.DataFrame(data)
      df.to_excel('URLsandAbstracts.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new `list`, in loop append output and last pass list of dictionary to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
out = []
for th in abstracturllist:

      response = requests.get(th)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
      #parse only abstract text from element <p></p>
      x = soup.select('div.abstr p')[0].text
      data = {'URL':th,'abstract':x}
      out.append(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(out)
print (df)
                                            URL  \
0  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31098966   
1  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31067303   
2  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31045693   

                                            abstract  
0  Delivering well-coordinated care is essential ...  
1  The proportion of Hispanics in the U.S. Vetera...  
2  VA and Medicare use among older Veterans has b...  

df.to_excel('URLsandAbstracts.xlsx')
```

Comment: I like this approach the best, except the it's only grabbing the first section (e.g., introduction section).  Is there a way to do this and grab the whole abstract?

Comment: @Brad AFK Then change `x = soup.select('div.abstr p')[0].text` to `x = soup.select('div.abstr')[0].prettify()`

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're overwriting your 'data' dictionary each time you loop the list.
Here's one way to fix it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
import pandas as pd

abstracturllist = ['https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31098966', 
'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31067303', 
'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31045693']

abstract_list=[] #create list for data

for th in abstracturllist:

    response = requests.get(th)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    x = soup.select('div.abstr')[0].prettify()    
    data = {'URL':[th],'abstract':[x]}

    abstract_list.append(data)

    df = pd.DataFrame(abslist)
    df.to_excel('URLsandAbstracts.xlsx')
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you! I also appreciate the explanation.  FYI, I changed abslist to abstract_list.  Thanks again!